# How to pre-interpret php in .html files on NGINX?

Tags: php, html, nginx

I have found a few threads on this, but the solutions I find do not work. I am trying to get my NGINX server to interpret the php inside of html files before sending the html files to the browser for processing. Here is some code inside my server bracket - inside of my only sites-enabled directory file, "default:"

```
location ~ \.(php|html|htm)$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                root            html;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;
                # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
                # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
```

Specifically, the part with (php|hmtl|htm) I was hoping to be the solution. However, php in my .html files are still commented out and not processed.

Not sure where security.limit_extensions parameter is? Here is my fastcgi-php.conf in snippets folder:

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Give the html files the extension of php.

Comment: Obviously the simplest solution. Circumstance prevents me from doing so. Hence the question.

Comment: You can shorten your regex to `location ~ \.(php|html?)$ { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is inside your `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` and if it is additionally limiting the PHP code processing via PHP-FPM somehow (I personally prefer to write PHP handlers locations myself), but at least you'll need to adjust the [`security.limit_extensions`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#:%7E:text=security.limit_extensions) parameter in your PHP-FPM pool configuration file (defaults to `.php .phar`). If it does not help, append the `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` file contents to your question.

Comment: @rickster26ter1 Seeing both `include fastcgi.conf;` in your `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` and `include fastcgi_params;` in the `default` server configuration is quite strange. Which one is actually exists/used? Additionally you can try `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.(?:php|html?))(/.*)$;` instead of the default `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;` (although I won't use that snippet file at all).